# How can I prevent property names in class diagrams from being sorted?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class-diagram

I tend to design my classes with properties sorted in an order that makes sense to me.  For example; I always make critical info like 'id' near the beginning, followed by less & less important data, and finally record meta data like 'create date' near the end.

But when I add the class to Visual Studio's (2010) class diagram, it sorts the properties alphabetically.  Is there anyway to turn this functionality off?

Edit (11/05/11):

For example, I have the following class

```
public class Email
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

But when I add it to my diagram, it displays properties in the following order:

```
CreateDate
EmailAddress
Id
Name
UpdateDate
UserId
```

Instead of the order I expect

```
Id
UserId
Name
EmailAddress
CreateDate
UpdateDate
```

Comment: have you found an answer?

Comment: @freshWoWer I haven't looked recently, but no.  Last time I checked, you had no control over it at all.

Comment: I also need that. Its very annoying - for example for enums - that the order is changed. There should be an option to not order at all. I keep a smart order in my classes by default and do not need help by the IDE. :(

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tkebx17.aspx

Comment: Thanks Rory, but that's not it.  I've updated my example to illustrate what I'm looking for more clearly.