# VS 2010 Class Diagram - Can Sort Alphabetically be removed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sorting, class-diagram

The Class Diagram in Visual Studio 2010 is a great feature but when it sorts "by kind" it also sorts the Fields and Methods Alphabetically.  I know that they can be sorted by Kind, Group or Alphabetically but I was hoping to know if there is a way to display the class components in the same order they are written in the .java files.

I looked at the [MSDN How to Customize the Class Class Diagrams: Class Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tkebx17%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but did not find much information on how to customize the display beyond the available menu buttons.

Please feel free to suggest another approach or Class Diagram Plugin or App if this is a lost cause.

Thanks.

Comment: Someone has already asked this, I'm pretty sure it's not possible even in VS2012 it look like. Outside of an addon of course but I doubt there was enough interest in it to make one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911385/how-can-i-prevent-property-names-in-class-diagrams-from-being-sorted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching for an answer to this question, it appears that no one has discovered a way to stop the diagram from sorting the elements alphabetically.